# ValueError while finding bigger number in list of two arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am kinda new in python programming...

I have a list of arrays smth like `[[0.3 0.6 0.8 1 1.2 2.4 3.5][1 1.2 1.7 1.9 2.1 2.2 2.3]]`

I want to compare those two arrays and find the first bigger number in first array(here it should be 2.4), but all I got is:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()...
```

**Code**:

```
medza_klzu_pocitadlo = True
medza_klzu = 0
kok = np.array([K] + [L])
for (q,w) in enumerate(kok):
    if (q,w)==0:
        pass
    else:
        if q >= w:
            medza_klzu = 0
        else: 
            medza_klzu = medza_klzu + 1
            if medza_klzu == 1 and medza_klzu_pocitadlo == True:
                medza_klzu_pocitadlo = False
                medza_klzu_1 = peror[q]
                klza = kok[0:q]
                hhelper = q

print('\n-----------------\n Medza Klzu = ',round((((sum(klza)))/hhelper),5),'\n-----------------\n')
```

Comment: What should happen if your list of arrays have 3 arrays in it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's not clear why you want 2.4 as desired output..

Comment: When you get an error you need to specify the line!

Comment: This ValueError is produced when you use a boolean array in a context that expects a simple scalar True/False.  An `if` statement is most likely.  Doing comparisons on numpy arrays produces boolean arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean mask indexing.

`arr[0] > arr[1]` gives you a numpy array with `True` at every index where the number in the first array is bigger than the number in the second array:

```
>>> arr
array([[ 0.3,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ,  1.2,  2.4,  3.5],
       [ 1. ,  1.2,  1.7,  1.9,  2.1,  2.2,  2.3]])
>>> arr[0] > arr[1]
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Indexing the array with this boolean mask gives us all numbers that are bigger than their counterparts:

```
>>> arr[0][arr[0] > arr[1]]
array([ 2.4,  3.5])
```

And then we simply take the first of these numbers:

```
>>> arr[0][arr[0] > arr[1]][0]
2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then you need to execute the following commands:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 2.4, 3.5])

b = np.array([1.0, 1.2, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3])

a[a > b][0]
```

This will give you the **expected 2.4**.
The answer is a modified version of answer given before by Aran-Fey.